# How to bind a RibbonButton to a command with parameters?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, ribbon, ribbon-button

I have a `ribbon` with many `ribbon-tabs` and `ribbon-buttons`.
This a common `Ribbon` that act on many views. I'm in a situation that I need a reference to the `XamDataGrid` in order for the `ribbon-button` hooked command to execute properly.

I have no clue how to pass a reference to the Ribbon or even deal with it keeping in mind this a common `Ribbon` menu.

Please note that I'm using `MVVM`.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Look at telerik site.
http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/mvvm-helpers/common-event-to-command-behavior

```
<telerik:EventToCommandBehavior.EventBindings>
<telerik:EventBinding Command="{Binding CustomCommand}" EventName="MouseLeftButtonDown" RaiseOnHandledEvents="True"
                      CommandParameter="This is a command parameter!"/>
```